# How to have orca read webpage in firefox on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, orca

I have orca install, and it works well on the desktop.
How do I make it read a webpage?
When I open firefox, orca tells me it is open, but how to read the content using orca?
I have caret browsing enables, and can navigate, but nothing is spoken.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably have to stop and restart Firefox after starting Orca. That worked for me just now.